# EVE-NG installation missing build folder from /lib/modules/kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers

I have EVE-NG ISO installed on a laptop and I'm trying to install a realtek driver for the wifi-card and I have to use 'make' to compile the code.
'Make' fails with the error message: "/lib/modules/5.17.8-eve-ng-uksm-wg+/build: No such file or directory. Stop."

Indeed that folder is missing. I tried to google the problem and it seems that similar problems of 'build' folder missing can be solved by installing the linux-headers. I tried 'apt install linux-headers-5.17.8-eve-ng-uksm-wk+' but it seems that I already have the latest version installed, yet 'build' folder is missing.

What can I do to get that folder and compile my driver?

Comment: Are there any other folders in /lib/modules? Do any of them have build directories?